# Peewee created new a entry successfully but lost the foreign-key value from select() query

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, peewee

Python version 3.6.8,
peewee version 3.10.0

I have 3 tables set up in a sqlite database using peewee.

```
Plan:
- id : int (primary key)
- plan_name : varchar (unique)
- status : int (foreign key for PlanStatus)
- category : int (foreign key for PlanCategory)

PlanStatus:
- id : int (primary key)
- value : varchar (unique)

PlanCategory:
- id : int (primary key)
- value : varchar (unique)
```

PlanStatus is an enum reference table, and PlanCategory is another enum reference table.  In the code below, PlanStatus is implemented naively with much boilerplate that would have to be duplicated for each other enum table. 
 In contrast, PlanCategory inherits from parent class EnumBaseModel, including 2 classmethods.  The goal is to reduce boilerplate with inheritance.

The result is that both enum tables were populated successfully, and you can access values from them with queries.  However, in creating a Plan entry, a row is added in the database (inspected in sqlite), but a select query returns the row with a missing value for the PlanCategory foreign key.

Creating tables and adding rows:

```
from peewee import *

DATABASE = SqliteDatabase('test.db')

# Base class with the inner Meta class defined
class BaseModel(Model):
    class Meta:
        database = DATABASE

# PlanStatus class, used with the following 2 methods
class PlanStatus(BaseModel):
    value = CharField(unique=True)

# Helper function for PlanStatus
def init_plan_status_values(values):
    for value in values:
        if not PlanStatus.select().where(PlanStatus.value == value).exists():
            PlanStatus.create(value=value)

# Helper function for PlanStatus
def get_plan_status(value):
    try:
        return PlanStatus.get(PlanStatus.value == value)
    except DoesNotExist as err:
        return None

# Base class with 2 classmethods
class EnumBaseModel(BaseModel):
    value = CharField(unique=True)

    @classmethod
    def init_values(cls, values):
        for value in values:
            if not cls.select().where(cls.value == value).exists():
                cls.create(value=value)

    @classmethod
    def get(cls, value):
        try:
            return cls.select().where(cls.value == value).get()
        except DoesNotExist as err:
            return None

# PlanCategory inherits EnumBaseModel class and its 2 classmethods
class PlanCategory(EnumBaseModel):
    pass

# Plan has 2 foreign keys
class Plan(BaseModel):
    plan_name = CharField(unique=True)
    status = ForeignKeyField(model=PlanStatus, backref='plans')
    category = ForeignKeyField(model=PlanCategory, backref='plans')

DATABASE.connect()
DATABASE.create_tables(
    [
        PlanStatus,
        PlanCategory,
        Plan
    ],
    safe=True
)

# Populating the enum values PlanStatus the explicit way above
init_plan_status_values(('STATUS-1', 'STATUS-2', 'STATUS-3'))

# Find status_2 the explicit way above
status_2 = get_plan_status('STATUS-2')

# Populating the enum values in PlanCategory using the inherited classmethod above
PlanCategory.init_values(('CATEGORY-1', 'CATEGORY-2', 'CATEGORY-3'))

# Find category_3 using the inherited classmethod above
category_3 = PlanCategory.get('CATEGORY-3')

# Add one plan
try:
    Plan.create(
        plan_name='not bad plan',
        status=status_2,
        category=category_3,
    )
except IntegrityError as err:
    print(err)
```

Now we see in sqlite3 the rows were added succesfully:

```
SQLite version 3.22.0 2018-01-22 18:45:57
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite> .tables
plan          plancategory  planstatus
sqlite> select * from planstatus;
1|STATUS-1
2|STATUS-2
3|STATUS-3
sqlite> select * from plancategory;
1|CATEGORY-1
2|CATEGORY-2
3|CATEGORY-3
sqlite> select * from plan;
1|not bad plan|2|3
sqlite>
```

Now checking the plan entry from the select() query, 'a_plan.status' is valid, but 'a_plan.category' is None.

```
# We see the references status_2 and category_3 are valid
print('status_2 = ', type(status_2), status_2, status_2.value)
print('category_3 = ', type(category_3), category_3, category_3.value)
print()

# We check the one plan in the table and see now the foreign-key value "category" is missing
a_plan = Plan.get()
print('a_plan: plan_name={}, status={}, category={}'.format(
    a_plan.plan_name,
    a_plan.status,
    a_plan.category
))
print()
```

Printed results:

```
status_2 =  <Model: PlanStatus> 2 STATUS-2
category_3 =  <Model: PlanCategory> 3 CATEGORY-3

a_plan: plan_name=not bad plan, status=2, category=None
```

Additionally, I found attributes 'status_id' and 'category_id' created by peewee.  At least 'category_id' still retains the foreign key int value.

```
# After inspecting dir(a_plan), found these attributes:
print('status = ', type(a_plan.status), a_plan.status)
print('status_id = ', type(a_plan.status_id), a_plan.status_id)
print('category = ', type(a_plan.category), a_plan.category)
print('category_id = ', type(a_plan.category_id), a_plan.category_id)
```

Printed results:

```
status =  <Model: PlanStatus> 2
status_id =  <class 'int'> 2
category =  <class 'NoneType'> None
category_id =  <class 'int'> 3
```

Is there any way to fix the problem so it can resolve 'a_plan.category'?

Answer (score 0):

You're overriding methods (.get) that are used by Peewee. Don't do that! I think you are making things too magical (and introducing queries all over the place in the process).

Try simplifying. I can almost guarantee the issue is in the overrides you're doing of classmethods that Peewee depends on.

Comment: Wow that was exactly it!  I renamed my classmethod to get_value, and it all works out now!  Thank you sir!  You've saved me!